# Populating Fragment with JSON data

Tags: android, json, android-layout, android-fragments, android-xml

I'm using [retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) to request JSON data from my site. Here is the `onCreate()` method from my `MainActivity` class:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(BASE_URL)
            .build();

    ApiEndpointInterface apiService = restAdapter.create(ApiEndpointInterface.class);

    apiService.getFeed(9, new Callback<Post>() {

        @Override
        public void success(Post post, Response response) {
            // do something
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
            retrofitError.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // Initialize the ViewPager and set an adapter
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

    // Bind the tabs to the ViewPager
    PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setViewPager(pager);
}
```

The JSON response looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "id":"1",
        "user_id":"1",
        ... more data ...
    },
    {
        "id":"2",
        "user_id":"1",
        ... more data ...
    },
    ... etc ...
]
```

I want to create a List within the Fragment, where each List item is populated by data from the returned JSON.

How do I create the List template and then populate it with the data?

Comment: I'd recommend looking at implementations of recyclerview. It seems like a good fit for what are you trying to do.

Comment: that's not a post, that's a list of posts

Answer (score 0):

Turn that JSON data into POJO/Bean objects, put them in an ArrayList, and use that arraylist in the adapter of your recyclerview/listview.

Answer (score 0):

You can use REST request libraries such as
[robospice](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice) or [volley](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley) and for the list, you can use recycler view.

You will need to implement an adapter for your recycler view as described on the documentation and populate the list.